# Split string into repeated acronym characters

Tags: java

I want to split the string

`"abcabcab"` 
into
 `"abc", "a", "b"` and so on.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: You can't achieve this, because your question/logic is not well defined.  Why should the first three letters `abc` form an acronym?  Why not `ab`, and then the following `c` is an acronym?

Comment: We are a question-and-answer site, not a coders-for-hire service. Please narrow your question down to a specific coding question that would be on-topic for this site.  See: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236) and [How to ask a good question when I'm not sure what I'm looking for?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262527/how-to-ask-a-good-question-when-im-not-sure-what-im-looking-for)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will give you some methods to split string. Those methods are in java.lang.String class. I hope that you can split any String whatever you want.

`String str = "abcdefgh";`

**1**    `str.substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex)`

Returns a string that is a substring of this string. 
*The index value is stared at 0.*

```
str.substring(1,3); //returns bc
```

**2**    `str.toCharArray();`

Converts this string to a new character array.

```
str.toCharArray(); //returns char array => [a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h]
```

**3** `charAt(int index);`

Returns the char value at the specified index.

```
str.charAt(0) // returns a
```

**5** `length();`

Returns the length of this string.

```
str.length(); //returns 8
```

If you want more click,   [Java™ Platform, Standard Edition 8
API Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/)

Answer (score 0):

You can play with the String like this :

```
String stringVal = "abcabcab";

//Split and add the last characters starting from the third one
List<String> split = new ArrayList<>(
        Arrays.asList(stringVal.substring(3, stringVal.length()).split(""))
);
//Add the three characters to your list
split.add(0, stringVal.substring(0, 3));

System.out.println(split);//Print the result
```

Outputs

```
[abc, a, b, c, a, b]
```